# how to get data from different uart in same callback function in stm32

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f4discovery

I am using the stm32f407 controller. I am using 2 uart - 2&3. I got interrupted the first time, but the second time I got interrupted on uart 2 - I did not get interrupted on uart3.

Below is my callback function:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(huart2.Instance == USART2)
    {
        gsm.RxData[gsm.RxDataCnt]=Uart_Rx_Buffer;
        gsm.RxDataCnt=(1+ gsm.RxDataCnt) % MAX_Buff_Size;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,&Uart_Rx_Buffer, 1);
    }
    else if(huart3.Instance == USART3)
    {
        lidar.RxData[lidar.RxDataCnt]=uart3_RX_Data;
        lidar.RxDataCnt=(1+ lidar.RxDataCnt) % MAX_LIDAR_BUFFER;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3,&uart3_RX_Data, 1);
        if(lidar.RxDataCnt >MAX_COUNT_BUFFER)
        {
            lidar.received = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide the full code along with explaining the scenario when you get this behavior (do you do something with the microcontroller?).

Answer (score 3):

The conditions in the `if`-statements are always true. You need to check the instance of the `huart` handle provided in the function argument, i.e.:

```
    if(huart->Instance == USART2)
```

and

```
    else if(huart->Instance == USART3)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have solved the problem. i am using function argument only huart->instance == USART2.